Why is my glob pattern matching the README file in "files to include" in Visual Studio Code?
I'm using the Visual Studio Code IDE, the search functionality allows you to specify file name, and also "files to include".
The "files to include" accepts glob patterns.
I'm trying to search a certain word, only in the files that start with the "select" prefix.
I've tried:
**/select*

According to the docs, the ** part will match any number of path segments, then it will match the select word, and then it should match "zero or more characters in a path segment", so I expect that path segment to be the same as the one that has the select prefix.
However, using this search config, the following file also appears in the results:
src/selectors/README.md

Why is this the case? Why is the last * matching ors/README.md, shouldn't it match in a path segment, and not any number of path segments (that's what the ** is for).
Funnily enough, using **/select** does seem to be showing only files that start with select, and that also doesn't make sense for me.

**/select/* add a slash after select if you dont want it to match "selectors"... * is a wildcard

@BenTaber that would match only files in any folder named "select", but I have no folder with that name. I'm trying to find in all files that start with select, in all folders of the repo. Thanks for your answer anyways!
